# Regex match repeating pattern only after string

Tags: java, regex

let a **PropDefinition** be a string of the form `prop\d+ (true|false)`

I have a string like:

```
((prop5 true))

sat
((prop0 false)
 (prop1 false)
 (prop2 true))
```

I'd like to extract the bottom **PropDefinitions** only after the text 'sat', so the matches should be:

```
prop0 false
prop1 false
prop2 true
```

I originally tried using `/(prop\d (?:true|false))/s` ([see example here](http://rubular.com/r/sS2LglhVgt)) but that obviously matches all **PropDefinitions** and I couldn't make it match repeats only after the `sat` string

I used rubular as an example above because it was convenient, but I'm really looking for the most language agnostic solution. If it's vital info, I'll most likely be using the regex in a Java application.

Comment: Splitting your input string before applying a regex will make your life easier.

Comment: What about nesting? What language? Does it support the `\G` anchor? Does it support recursion?

Comment: I'd love a version which didn't involve splitting the string. I was really looking for a regex which would work out of curiosity. I could absolutely split on sat and then just regex the text which comes after, but I'd learn less :)

Comment: Added a language clarification. Ideally I'd like to know a general Regex solution but at a push, I'll likely be implementing in Java.

Comment: @PeterHamilton, have you tried my solution in Java? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. It does not require a split and returns all matches. I might even be able to adapt it to also work in Ruby now that I just checked a reference that shows lookbehinds not working in Ruby but lookaheads working in Ruby and most RegEx engines.

Answer (score 0):

```
str =<<-Q
((prop5 true))

sat
((prop0 false)
 (prop1 false)
 (prop2 true))
Q

p str[/^sat(.*)/m, 1].scan(/prop\d+ (?:true|false)/)

# => ["prop0 false", "prop1 false", "prop2 true"]
```

Comment: Your regexp matches one at a time too. The magic happens in method `scan`, not your regexp.

Comment: I return a separate match per property, no use in delivering 1 string when you have to read properties later individually anyway?

Answer (score 0):

When you have patterns that are very different in nature as in this case (string after `sat` and selecting the specific patterns), it is usually better to express them in multiple regexes rather than trying to do it with a single regex.

```
s = <<_
((prop5 true))

sat
((prop0 false)
 (prop1 false)
 (prop2 true))
_

s.split(/^sat\s+/, 2).last.scan(/prop\d+ (?:true|false)/)
# => ["prop0 false", "prop1 false", "prop2 true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion has to do with SingleLine vs MultiLine matching.  The patterns below work for me and return all matches in a single execution and without requiring a preliminary operation to split the string.

This one requires SingleLine mode to be specified separately (as in .Net RegExOptions):

```
(?<=sat.*)(prop\d (?:true|false))
```

This one specifies SingleLine mode inline which works with many, but not all, RegEx engines:

```
(?s)(?<=sat.*)(?-s)(prop\d (?:true|false))
```

You don't *need* to turn SingleLine mode off via the `(?-s)` but I think it is clearer in its intent.

The following pattern also toggles SingleLine mode inline, but uses a Negative LookAhead instead of a Positive LookBehind as it seems (according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)  [be sure to select Ruby and Java from the drop-downs]) the Ruby engine doesn't support LookBehinds--Positive or Negative--depending on the version, and even then doesn't allow quantifiers (also noted by @revo in a comment below). This pattern should work in Java, .Net, most likely Ruby, and others:

```
(prop\d (?:true|false))(?s)(?!.*sat)(?-s)
```

Comment: Look behind assertion doesn't support quantifiers in ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
\s+[(]+\K(prop\d (?:true|false)(?=[)]))
```

[**Live demo**](http://rubular.com/r/sKtY47v0n0)

Answer (score 0):

If Ruby can support the `\G` anchor this is one solution.
It looks nasty, but several things are going on.
1. It only allows a single nest (outer plus many inners)
2. It will not match invalid forms that don't comply with `'(prop\d true|false)'`

Without condition 2, it would be alot easier which is an indicator that a two regex
solution would do the same. First to capture the outer form `sat((..)..(..)..)` 
second to globally capture the inner form `(prop\d true|false)`.

Can be done in a single regex, though this is going to be hard to look at, but should work (test case below in Perl).

```
# (?:(?!\A|sat\s*\()\G|sat\s*\()[^()]*(?:\((?!prop\d[ ](?:true|false)\))[^()]*\)[^()]*)*\((prop\d[ ](?:true|false))\)(?=(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\))

 (?:
      (?! \A | sat \s* \( )
      \G                            # Start match from end of last match
   |                              # or,
      sat \s* \(                    # Start form 'sat ('
 )
 [^()]*                        # This check section consumes invalid inner '(..)' forms
 (?:                           # since we are looking specifically for '(prop\d true|false)'
      \( 
      (?!
           prop \d [ ] 
           (?: true | false )
           \)
      )
      [^()]* 
      \)
      [^()]* 
 )*                            # End section, do optionally many times
 \( 
 (                             # (1 start), match inner form '(prop\d true|false)'
      prop \d [ ] 
      (?: true | false )
 )                             # (1 end)
 \)
 (?=                           # Look ahead for end form  '(..)(..))'
      (?:
           [^()]* 
           \( [^()]* \)
      )*
      [^()]* 
      \) 
 )
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ($str =~ /(?:(?!\A|sat\s*\()\G|sat\s*\()[^()]*(?:\((?!prop\d[ ](?:true|false)\))[^()]*\)[^()]*)*\((prop\d[ ](?:true|false))\)(?=(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\))/g)
{
   print "'$1'\n";
}

__DATA__
((prop10 true))
sat
((prop3 false)
(asdg) 

(propa false)

 (prop1 false)
 (prop2 true)
)
((prop5 true))
```

Output >>

```
'prop3 false'
'prop1 false'
'prop2 true'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/(?<=sat).*?(prop\d (true|false))/m
```

**Match group 1** is what you want. See [example](http://rubular.com/r/VCFCqStIEa).

**BUT**, I would really recommend split the string first. It's much easier.

Comment: You only return prop0 false, no other matches are made. He wanted all 3 prop definitions.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers It matches one at a time. Repeat it and you will get all of them.